# asp.net selecting a checkbox from the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to get checkbox value ,using c#
In grid view the datasource is from oracle
i have added the checkbox but the value is not coming
please help me in checking the value of check box
this is for selecting the candidate if the checkbox is selected the particular candidate name is selected and the candidate names are appended
in a string

Comment: please add more specific details. how is your databinding? what do you mean by the value is not coming? you can't get the value or you can't see the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop thru each row of the gridview and check whether  the checkbox is selected or not-

foreach(Gridviewrow gridrow in gridview.Rows)
{

Checkbox check=(Checkbox)gridrow.findControl("check");
  if(check.checked)
    {
       //Write logic here
    }
}